# sql 2008 metadata modified date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, metadata

Is there a way to identify the timestamp when an object(table/view/stored proc...) was modified ?

there's a refdate in sysobjects but it's always the same as crdate atleast in my case and i know that alter view/alter table/alter proc commands have been run many times post creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**modify_date** in [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx):

> Date the object was last modified by
>   using an ALTER statement. If the
>   object is a table or a view,
>   modify_date also changes when a
>   clustered index on the table or view
>   is created or altered.